# How to disable nginx from elastic beanstalk platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I'm switching from nginx to Caddy so I set up Caddy and created a new AMI. When I deploy this AMI to my EB environment, it fails to launch because nginx fails to start during the launch.

Using EB platform Ruby 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2, how is it possible to prevent nginx from launching?

Comment: Which EB platform are you using exactly?

Comment: @Marcin Ruby 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2

Comment: If you are using custom EB AMI, can you create the ami with nginx disabled? `sudo systemctl stop nginx` and `sudo systemctl stop nginx`?

Comment: @Marcin I had already done that and sudo systemctl disable nginx - it isn't enough. The launch script still tries to start nginx.

Comment: Maybe `sudo systemctl disable nginx` ?

Comment: Try to add ```sudo systemctl mask nginx``` as sometimes stop and disabling it is not enough.

Comment: You may find that it will be easier to just run it on your own ec2 instance, rather then hack-up how EB works.

Answer (score 2):

If you *choose* to modify the default AMI, and not create a new one, then ...to override the Elastic Beanstalk `nginx configuration`, add the following line to your `nginx.conf` *per* **AWS** documentation, do the above "*...to pull in the Elastic Beanstalk configurations for Enhanced health reporting and monitoring, **automatic application mappings**, and static files.*"

Have a look [here...](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) I posted some of those *copied* sample snippets for you below to walk you through,

- a) you would setup your daemon by *overriding* the `nginx default config`,
- then b) tell the overridden ngix config to look for `Caddys` extensions
- c) and that extension would read its config file

---

```
 // this where you over ride nginx config
 include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
```

- a) For e.g. Configuring Apache HTTPD

The Tomcat, Node.js, PHP, and Python platforms allow you to choose the Apache HTTPD proxy server as an alternative to nginx. This isn't the default. The following example configures Elastic Beanstalk to use Apache HTTPD.

Example, here *we replace the reverse proxy with* `apache` .ebextensions/httpd-proxy.config (you try caddy)

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:
    ProxyServer: apache
```

---

**Background:**

By default it ships with Nginx as the reverse proxy on port 80 to find your app. on EBS. So, you have two options a 1) `new Custom AMI` or 2) `Modifying your AMI`

"*...Proxy configuration files provided in the .ebextensions/nginx directory should move to the .platform/nginx platform hooks directory. For details, expand the Reverse Proxy Configuration section in Extending Elastic Beanstalk Linux platforms.*"

Then look at `predeploy` and `postdeploy config options` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)

[image: Elastic Beanstalk Configuration]